# Creating a countdown (mm:ss)

Tags: vb.net

how would i create a countdown in the format mm:ss with the following data:

```
Dim secCount As String = 0
Dim button1 As Decimal


Private Sub button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles button.Click
    button1 = InputBox("Set button1 for how many minutes?", "button1", "5")
    If Timer1.Enabled = True Then
        Timer1.Enabled = False           
    Else 
        secCount = 60            
        Timer1.Interval = 1000            
        Timer1.Enabled = True
        Timer1.Start()            
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim mincount As String = button1
    secCount = secCount - 1
    If secCount = "-1" Then
        secCount = "59"
    End If
    If mincount = button1 Then
        secCount = secCount.PadLeft(2, "0"c)
        Label6.Text = (mincount + ":" + secCount)
        If secCount = button1 Then
            MsgBox("button1")
        End If
End Sub
```

the label is holding the countdown mm:ss
i am trying to get the mincount and seccount to work but at the moment only the seccount will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim selfdestruct1 As Decimal
Dim mincount As String
Dim secCount As String = 0  

Private Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Selfdestruct.Click
    Dim wholepart As Decimal
    Dim fractionpart As Decimal

    If Timer1.Enabled = True Then
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        MsgBox("button has been cancelled")
        Console.WriteLine("button has been cancelled")
        Label6.Visible = False
    Else
        button1 = InputBox("Set button1 for how many minutes?", "BUTTON1", "5")
        wholepart = Math.Truncate(button1)
        fractionpart = button1 - wholepart
        secCount = 60            
        Timer1.Interval = 1000            
        Timer1.Enabled = True
        Timer1.Start()
        Label6.Visible = True
    End If
    mincount = wholepart
    secCount = fractionpart * 60
    secCount = secCount.PadLeft(2, "0"c)
    Label6.Text = (mincount + ":" + secCount)
End Sub
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    secCount = secCount - 1
    If secCount = "-1" Then
        secCount = "59"
        mincount = mincount - 1
    End If
    secCount = secCount.PadLeft(2, "0"c)
    Label6.Text = (mincount + ":" + secCount)
    If mincount = 0 And secCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox("YAY!")
    End If
End Sub
```

label6 holds the countdown value

Answer (score 0):

Your `mincount` variable gets defined and initialized in your timer routine, doesn't get changed, and then you compare it to the original value again.

you might want to consider this: rather than juggling around two decrementing values -- minutes and seconds --, set your initial secCount to 60*minutes and count that down. In your interval routine, display `secCount/60` and `secCount % 60` for minutes and seconds.

Comment: Solved, how? That could help others.

Comment: @OliverHands: If you problem is now solved, and this answer helped solve it, please consider accepting and/or upvoting this answer. If you had to do some research yourself, you can post it as a separate answer. A common practice here on SO is to give credit to whomever is trying to help you. So if you used the above answer to produce a solution, please still consider accepting and/or upvoting it, even though it may have not fully addressed your issue.